# Using the dominated convergence theorem to bound the integral of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The following claim is used in the solution to problem 9.4 in Jacod and Protter's *Probability Essentials*:

**Claim:** Let $X\in\mathcal{L}^{1}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ (where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $P$ is a probability measure). Then for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an M such that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} |X| 1_{\{\lvert X\rvert>M\}} dP <\varepsilon
\end{equation}

**Background:** Jacod and Protter suggest this follows from Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem. I am new to measure theory and am looking for a proof of the claim using the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following two facts.

$1$-) $\lvert X \rvert 1_{\{\lvert X \rvert > M \}} \leq \lvert X\rvert$ and $E[ \lvert X\rvert] < \infty$ since $X$ is $L^1$.

$2$-) $\lvert X \rvert 1_{\{\lvert X \rvert > M \}} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely as $M$ goes to infinity. This is true because $X$ being $L^1$ implies that $\lvert X \rvert$ is almost surely finite.

Then the DCT gives you

$$\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}E[\lvert X \rvert 1_{\{\lvert X \rvert > M \}}] = E[\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \lvert X \rvert 1_{\{\lvert X \rvert > M \}}] = 0$$

In other words I can make $E[\lvert X \rvert 1_{\{\lvert X \rvert > M \}}]$ arbitrarily small by choosing a large enough $M$, which is the statement in the claim.

Comment: This looks good, thanks. One question: Is a lebesgue-integrable function almost everywhere bounded? This was one thing I was unsure about but is something used in your proof.

Comment: No I didn't use such a thing in my proof. Being a.s. finite does not mean being a.s. bounded. Take a Gaussian r.v. for example. I merely used the fact that the probability that $\lvert X\rvert$ takes the value infinity is $0$.

Comment: Okay, so is it true that any lebesgue-integrable function is almost everywhere finite?

Comment: @möbius yes. the proof is simple. start with $X$ being integrable. now suppose that it is not almost surely finite. that would imply $X$ not being integrable, which is a contradiction. the other direction is not true though.

Comment: Okay great, this was very helpful thanks

Comment: @möbius you are welcome